# Verb fare, first person singular: faccio vs fo

Tags: word-usage, verbs, regional

On Wiktionary the first person singular for "fare" both lists faccio and fo. I've asked an Italian and they have never heard of "fo". I did some research on the net and found an [explanation](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/fo-saccio.338391/) (if I understood everything correctly) that fo is a regional form (Tuscan) and therefore not universally understood/used.

Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Io fo" is actually an alternative form for the present indicative of the first person. Its usage is mainly literary and archaic [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=io%20faccio%2C%20io%20fo&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cio%20faccio%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cio%20fo%3B%2Cc0) (io faccio vs io fo). It is also used as a dialectal expression in Tuscany as far as I know.

***[Fare](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/F/fare_1.shtml) (v).***

> - ***(ind.pres. faccio o fò***, fai, fa, facciamo, fate, fanno, imperf. facévo ecc., pass.rem. féci, facésti, féce, facémmo, facéste, fécero, fut. farò ecc.; congiunt.pres. fàccia ecc., imperf. facéssi ecc.; cond. farèi ecc.; part.pres. facènte, pass. fatto; ger. facèndo; imp. fa o fa' o fai, fate)
> - eh! io fo l'orecchio del mercante, (Manzoni)
>   [Treccani.it](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/lessico/lessico_026.html)

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the [entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fo#Italian) with your information.

Comment: @JanBerkel: It might help to keep in mind that Standard Italian is historically based on the dialect of Florence, so a Tuscan use is, in a sense, more at home in Standard Italian, than one from other regions.

Comment: And, @JanBerkel, may I suggest to consult, rather than crowdsourced Wiktionary, actual dictionaries such as some of those listed [here](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/a/123/37), and in particular Treccani, Sabatini-Coletti, De Mauro and old but precious Tommaseo?

Comment: @DaG I'm aware of the varying quality of Wiktionary entries, I don't use it exclusively, but it's very handy for language cross-reference, esp. etymologies.

In this particular case I had actually consulted Treccani which does list "fo" under "fare" but does not explain anything about its origin or usage information. And it confusingly lists "fo" before "faccio", which would indicate that it is the more common form.

Comment: It should be noted, however, that _fo_ is the more commonly used form after the prefix *dis-*: [“disfo le valigie”](https://tinyurl.com/ybudx4xd)